# Why is the definition of conditional probability recursive

Tags: probability, recursion

The definition of conditional probability after Kolmogorov seems to be recursive without a base case. It says

$\text{P}(A|B) = \frac{\text{P}(A \cap B)}{\text{P}(B}$

Now, $\text{P}(A \cap B)$ is $\text{P}(A)\text{P}(B | A)$

So we get

$\newcommand{\prob}{\text{P}}
\begin{align*}
  \prob(A | B) = & \frac{\text{P}(A \cap B)}{\text{P}(B}\\
  = & \frac{\prob(A)\prob(B|A)}{\prob(B)}\\
  = & \frac{\prob(A)\left[ \frac{\prob(B)\prob(A|B)}{\prob(A)} \right]}{\prob(B)}\\
  = & \frac{\prob(A)\left[ \frac{\prob(B) \left[ \frac{\prob(A)\prob(B|A)}{\prob(B)}  \right]}{\prob(A)} \right]}{\prob(B)}\\
  = & \frac{\prob(A)\left[ \frac{\prob(B) \left[ \frac{\prob(A)   \left[    \frac{\prob(B)\prob(A|B)}{\prob(A)}   \right]   }{\prob(B)}  \right]}{\prob(A)} \right]}{\prob(B)}\\
                 & \vdots
\end{align*}$

And the recursion goes on.

If one does not actually calculate $\prob(A| B)$ like this for instance:

$$\prob(A | B) = \frac{\#(B, A)}{\sum_{e_i}\#(B,e_i)} $$ you never get a base case for the recursion. Why is that?

Comment: No. The probability of the intersection is not *defined* as you say: the intersection of two measurable sets is measurable (by definition of a sigma algebra) and does not need any further definition. All you're doing here is repeatedly *applying* the definition of conditional probability.

Answer (score 2):

**I will answer with an ironic (though hopefully enlightening) example:**

Let $y=2x$, hence $x=y/2$.

Therefore $y=2(y/2)$.

Therefore $y=2(2x/2)$.

Therefore $y=2(2y/2/2)$.

Therefore $y=2(2(2x)/2/2)$.

Therefore $y=2(2(2y/2)/2/2)$.

Therefore $y=2(2(2(2x)/2)/2/2)$.

Therefore $y=2(2(2(2y/2)/2)/2/2)$.

...

Comment: I take it that the down-voter didn't feel very enlightened...?

Comment: I upvoted -- good example! Tho you could've said (to be totally explicit for the student) "does this mean my definition is "recursive without a base case"?"

Comment: @symplectomorphic: Yes, well... I wasn't quite sure how to phrase this, so I was just hoping that the title alone could illustrate my intention. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no recursion. $P(A \cap B)$ and $P(B)$ are both well-defined and then you define $P(A |B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$. If you look closely at your calculations, then you will see that the equation

$$P(A | B) = \frac{P(A) \frac{P(B) P(A|B)}{P(A)}}{P(B)}$$
simplifies to $P(A|B) = P(A|B)$.

Comment: but $P(A\cap B)$ is defined as $P(A)P(B|A)$. And there is the recursion... sorry, I am apparently missing something, but I don't see what.

Comment: @user3578468: no, that is *not* how the probability of the intersection is defined; that is simply a *consequence* of the very definition of conditional probability. (of course defining it as you say would be circular.) read my comment.

Comment: $(A \cap B)$ is not defined as $P(A)P(B|A)$. If $A$ and $B$ are events, then $A \cap B$ is also an event. Therefore you can plug it into the probability measure. $P(A \cap B)$ is simply this value.

Comment: Ok, but what about this then? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#As_an_axiom_of_probability  There is says it *is* defined like that.

Comment: @user3578468: that page is defining *conditional probability*, **not** *the probability of the intersection*! the whole point is that you define the conditional probability in terms of probabilities that are *already* defined, namely $P(A)$ or $P(B)$ and $P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I don't understand your answer. Why does the subsection I linked not define the intersection, when it has the equation defining the intersection as its subject?